# dissmissible option not working through panel api

Tags: jquery-mobile

From the panel api: http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#option-dismissible

I have tried to set the dismissible option after initialization on both predefined and dynamic panel elements using the default way as indicated in the api.

At first I thought I was doing something wrong, but now after further testing it seems like a bug:

In both cases upon initializing dismissible:

```
<div data-role="panel" data-dismissible="true">

</div>
```

Or:

```
$( ".selector" ).panel({
    dismissible: true
});
```

The getter works fine:

```
var dismissible = $( ".selector" ).panel( "option", "dismissible" );
```

The setter sets the value (and the getter picks up changed value), but the panel has no further effect:

```
$( ".selector" ).panel( "option", "dismissible", false );
```

Unless this is not supposed to work this way as all other options I've been able to change to this point.

I have tried this in newest version of Jquery Mobile 1.4, including 1.4.4 and 1.4.5.

Comment: True, it is a bug. Once you set `dismissible` to `false`, the _dismissible div_ should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.

Comment: A fix http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/y91bqjum/ open a ticket: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues

Comment: Thanks Omar for the fix, but is there a way to change the value back to true once more? ie: http://jsfiddle.net/ffL0dmpz/1/

Comment: In my case I need full control of this option as this is a SPA with lots of dynamic Ajax requests.

Comment: In that case, hide/show it. Dismissible false: `$(".ui-panel-dismiss").addClass("ui-screen-hidden");`. Dismissible true: `$(".ui-panel-dismiss").removeClass("ui-screen-hidden");`

Comment: ticket opened: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7882